# what does this freq mean? pandas pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=100, freq="1953U")

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas. Can someone please help me understand what does this freq value mean "1953U". I know that "U" is for micro seconds. What I am not sure is the 1953 number before "U".

```
pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=100, freq="1953U")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it returns a `datetimeindex`  for every `1953 micro seconds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the frequency is 1953 microseconds. You can have your answer by actually running the command :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=100, freq="1953U")
DatetimeIndex([       '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.001953',
               '2000-01-01 00:00:00.003906', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.005859',...
```

Comment: Thank you. I did run the code. But I didn't pay close attention to the difference.

Comment: You have one date every 1953 microseconds : XXX.001953, XXX.003906 (1953x2), etc...

Answer (score 0):

`1953` is the multiplier. You can find details in the pandas documentation:

> **freq** : string or DateOffset, default ‘D’ (calendar daily) Frequency
>   strings can have multiples, e.g. ‘5H’

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range

> Under the hood, these frequency strings are being translated into an
>   instance of pandas DateOffset, which represents a regular frequency
>   increment. Specific offset logic like “month”, “business day”, or “one
>   hour” is represented in its various subclasses.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects